Volume down button not working after battery replacement
I recently replaced the battery in my iPhone 12 with a third party battery and now the volume down isn’t working. Is that a result of the battery not being apple certified? I am pretty sure the hardware isn’t damaged in any way.

Have you checked if you can still adjust the volume up and down using control centre ie. on the screen ?

If someone performed a hardware operation on your phone, and it isn't working: then take it back for them to sort out.

I was the one who did the repair. I can still use the on screen volume fine it’s just the button that doesn’t work. I was thinking maybe it was a software issue?

"I was thinking maybe it was a software issue?" - I'm more inclined to think it is a hardware problem as a result of your repair. If you completely reset your iPhone to factory settings, but the problem persists, it is clearly a HW problem.

Ok. I will give it a shot.
